# Anylogic Error： <unknown> (Path) : The length is zero

Tags: anylogic

I created a job shop model and when I try to run the model, the system give me the feedback:

> Error during model creation:
>
> root:
>
> (Path) : The length is zero
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: root:
>
> (Path) : The length is zero
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.MarkupShape.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.Path$1.j(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractCurve.initialize(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.Path.f(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.MarkupShape.initialize(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.Path.(Unknown Source)
>
> at
>   jobshopfinal.Main._createPersistentElementsBP0_xjal(Main.java:6451)
>
> at jobshopfinal.Main.(Main.java:6946)
>
> at jobshopfinal.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:158)
>
> at jobshopfinal.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:1)

I am not sure what caused this error. Have anyone faced the same problem. I need help to solve this error. This is the link for my model: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ixp4y5avosfdwaq/AADCZMm9CwczCJAlb7ehyx-ga?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen when the length of a path is zero, meaning that the initial point of the path and the end point of the path are in the exact same location, so the relative points will be always zero:
[image: relative points are zero]

Your job is then to remove that path immediately from the network or add some length to it.

In your model, this error occurs in path 21:
[image: the path]

You can always find it in the project panel if you are unable to click on it:
[image: the path in the project panel]